# Como sumar todas las columnas (Cantidades) de mis tablas en PHP al momento de que el usuario elija el rango por fecha

Tags: php

Buenas tardes tengo una gran duda, tengo un proyecto PHP el cual me arroja las sumas totales de cada tabla, pero quisiera que al elegir por medio de un select (lista) o input con boton me lo desglosara por el mes o el año seleccionado previamente por el usuario.

Si alguien me puede ayudar se los agradecería demasiado.

[image: Suma totales por mes y año en MYSQL]

[image: Panel principal]

en la bd hago individual esta consulta:
SELECT sum(cantidad_doctor) from tbldoctores WHERE ExpenseDate BETWEEN '2020-09-01' AND '2020-09-31'

pero me gustaria que hubiera un select que el usuario eligiera por mes y año y diera el total de la fecha elegida.

Mi duda es como seria en PHP???

**Actualizacion -----------------------------------------

Tengo una duda para sumar todos los campos y dar el total entre las fechas elegidas por el usuario como seria en mysql??

Tengo esto pero me da error:

select ((select sum(cantidad_factura) from tblcontador)+(select sum(cantidad_doctor) from tbldoctores)+(select sum(cantidad) from tblecoentorno)+(select sum(cantidad) from tblentrada_plan)+(select sum(cantidad) from tblfacturas)+(select sum(cantidad) from tbltrabajadores) +(select sum(cantidad_envio) from tblmaquila)) WHERE ExpenseDate BETWEEN '2020-10-01' AND '2020-10-31'

y el diseño asi quedaria bueno al menos asi lo implemente yo.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que has intentado al momento?, Lee [ask]

Comment: en bd hago las consultas individuales asi: SELECT sum(cantidad_doctor) from tbldoctores WHERE ExpenseDate BETWEEN '2020-09-01' AND '2020-09-31' pero me gustaria que me las diera todas y no se como seria

Comment: Todo lo relevante a tu duda colócalo en la publicación

Comment: Crea un formulario con dos _input_ tipo _date_ y, al procesarlo, tomas los valores para incluirlos en la consulta. Edita la pregunta y agrega lo que hayas intentado (HTML + PHP) para poder tratar de ayudarte.

Comment: para sumar todos las columnas de cantidad de cada tabla por medio de las fechas que el usuario elija como seria ??

Comment: Tengo esto pero me da un error!!!      select ((select sum(cantidad_factura) from tblcontador)+(select sum(cantidad_doctor) from tbldoctores)+(select sum(cantidad) from tblecoentorno)+(select sum(cantidad) from tblentrada_plan)+(select sum(cantidad) from tblfacturas)+(select sum(cantidad) from tbltrabajadores) +(select sum(cantidad_envio) from tblmaquila)) WHERE ExpenseDate BETWEEN '2020-10-01' AND '2020-10-31'

Comment: e individual si puedo pero para elejir a todos no se

Comment: podrias ordenar tu pregunta?? no se entiende que estas preguntando ni a que apunta tu pregunta... ese select esta mal porque le falta un from.. igual tene en cuenta que no somos magos..y decir tiene un error (Sin decirnos que error es) implica que hagamos magia para saber que puede estar mal...

Comment: A ver amigo tu duda es con php o mysql? porque para sacar todo eso que quieres lo puedes hacer con php, pero veo que te estas enredando con mysql

Comment: Si perdon mi duda es con PHP, como puedo hacer para sumas todas las columnas (cantidades) de las tablas que tengo en mi BD al momento de que elija el usuario el rango por fechas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolvi de la siguiente forma:**

```
select sum(Total) from (select sum(cantidad_doctor) as total from tbldoctores where ExpenseDate between '2020-01-01' and '2020-10-31'
union 
select sum(cantidad_factura) as total from tblcontador where ExpenseDate between '2020-01-01' and '2020-10-31'
union 
select sum(cantidad) as total from tblecoentorno where ExpenseDate between '2020-01-01' and '2020-10-31'
union 
select sum(cantidad) as total from tblentrada_plan where ExpenseDate between '2020-01-01' and '2020-10-31'
union 
select sum(cantidad) as total from tblfacturas where ExpenseDate between '2020-01-01' and '2020-10-31'
union 
select sum(cantidad_estudio+cantidad_envio) as total from tblmaquila where ExpenseDate between '2020-01-01' and '2020-10-31'
union 
select sum(cantidad) as total from tbltrabajadores where ExpenseDate between '2020-01-01' and '2020-10-31')
tabla
```